# How to implement "Bilinear loss" function in R/tensorflow

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, loss-functions, tensorflow

I was reading Resheff et al 2017[1] and trying to implement their idea for a loss function in R. I am not sure if I understand correctly.

It appears simple enough:

> Specifically, let $a_{i,j}$ denote the relative cost associated with
>   assigning the label $j$ to an example whose correct label is $i$, and
>   let $A = {a_{i,j}} \in  \mathscr{R}^{k \times k}$ denote the penalty
>   matrix. Using $A$ we define two related loss functions: The Bilinear
>   loss is defined as:
>
> $L_{B} = y^{T} A \hat{y}$

I did the following, but am not sure:

**R code:**

```
set.seed(1234)

# Helper softmax function
softmax = function(logits){ exp(logits)/sum(exp(logits)) }


# Define penalty matrix (multipliers for the loss)
penaltyMat = matrix(1, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
penaltyMat[1, 3] = penaltyMat[3, 1] = 2
rownames(penaltyMat) = colnames(penaltyMat) = c("A", "B", "C")


# Generate target (true classes)
targ = matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 3)
sel  = sample(3, nrow(targ), replace = T)
for(i in 1:length(sel)){ targ[i, sel[i]] = 1 }

# Generate logits (for predicted classes)
logits = matrix(runif(length(targ), -10, 10), nrow = 10, ncol = 3)


# Calculate Bilinear Loss
BilinearLoss = targ*(softmax(logits) %*% penaltyMat)
```

**Results:**

```
> penaltyMat
  A B C
A 1 1 2
B 1 1 1
C 2 1 1


> targ
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0
 [3,]    0    1    0
 [4,]    0    1    0
 [5,]    0    0    1
 [6,]    0    1    0
 [7,]    1    0    0
 [8,]    1    0    0
 [9,]    0    1    0
[10,]    0    1    0


> logits
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
 [1,]  3.8718258 -3.6677509 -0.8781704
 [2,]  0.8994967 -3.9461326 -4.6962666
 [3,] -4.3453283 -6.8190799 -3.9065559
 [4,]  8.4686697 -9.2000816  0.1461374
 [5,] -4.1536832 -5.6240092 -6.3780758
 [6,]  6.7459126  6.2119710  5.1934127
 [7,] -4.2755343  0.5139509 -5.9750392
 [8,] -4.6635844  8.2931633 -4.8238036
 [9,] -6.2655442  6.6269009  9.8430084
[10,] -5.3554818 -9.0845947  6.1470468


> BilinearLoss 
                 A            B            C
 [1,] 1.608557e-03 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
 [2,] 0.000000e+00 8.182605e-05 0.000000e+00
 [3,] 0.000000e+00 1.124311e-06 0.000000e+00
 [4,] 0.000000e+00 1.567648e-01 0.000000e+00
 [5,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.208276e-06
 [6,] 0.000000e+00 5.032116e-02 0.000000e+00
 [7,] 5.563614e-05 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
 [8,] 1.314996e-01 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
 [9,] 0.000000e+00 6.443034e-01 0.000000e+00
[10,] 0.000000e+00 1.537728e-02 0.000000e+00
```

Also, eventually I would use this in tensorflow, which I am guessing is:

**R:**

```
BilinearLoss = targ*(tf$matmul(tf$softmax(logits), penaltyMat))
```

**Python:**

```
BilinearLoss = targ*(tf.matmul(tf.softmax(logits), penaltyMat))
```

Does this look correct?

[1] "Here we present the bilinear-loss (and related log-bilinear-loss) which differentially penalizes the different wrong assignments of the model." https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.06062

**Edit:**

Well I messed with the first row of logits and it affected the other rows so my above interpretation must be wrong:

```
logits[1,] = c(2, 0, 0)
targ*(softmax(logits) %*% penaltyMat)
```

**Edit 2:**

Ok... well looking at it again in the morning I see I had a dumb bug where I was not applying softmax by row. The softmax should look like this instead:

```
# Helper softmax function
softmax = function(logits){ 
    t(apply(logits, 1, function(x) exp(x)/sum(exp(x))))
}
```

The final result is then:

```
> BilinearLoss
             A B        C
 [1,] 1.008573 0 0.000000
 [2,] 0.000000 1 0.000000
 [3,] 0.000000 1 0.000000
 [4,] 0.000000 1 0.000000
 [5,] 0.000000 0 1.747393
 [6,] 0.000000 1 0.000000
 [7,] 1.001505 0 0.000000
 [8,] 1.000002 0 0.000000
 [9,] 0.000000 1 0.000000
[10,] 0.000000 1 0.000000
```

So, for example, sample 7 has a true class of "A", and predictions for each class (softmax) are 8.235724e-03, 9.902590e-01, and 1.505276e-03. So even though the wrong class (B) is predicted with high confidence, we have a low bilinear loss since the penalty for confusing A with B is low?

The same thing can be seen for sample 8. For sample 1 the correct class was predicted and the loss is also low, while for sample 5 The correct class was C, but A was predicted so the loss is relatively high.

It seems to roughly make sense.

Here are the class probabilities I was using in the paragraph above:

```
> softmax(logits)
              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
 [1,] 9.909002e-01 5.267849e-04 8.572999e-03
 [2,] 9.885562e-01 7.772689e-03 3.671067e-03
 [3,] 3.794965e-01 3.197946e-02 5.885240e-01
 [4,] 9.997571e-01 2.120573e-08 2.429208e-04
 [5,] 7.473933e-01 1.717888e-01 8.081794e-02
 [6,] 5.561712e-01 3.260773e-01 1.177515e-01
 [7,] 8.235724e-03 9.902590e-01 1.505276e-03
 [8,] 2.360229e-06 9.999956e-01 2.010813e-06
 [9,] 9.706548e-08 3.856405e-02 9.614359e-01
[10,] 1.010441e-05 2.426485e-07 9.999897e-01
```